# DAX: Average distinct values per day

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've got some categories spread over a number of days. The same category can occur several times on the same date. How can I get the average number of distinct categories per day?

**Dataset:**

```
Date,Category
11.10.2018,A
11.10.2018,B
11.10.2018,C
12.10.2018,A
12.10.2018,A
12.10.2018,A
13.10.2018,B
13.10.2018,B
```

**Table from data view:**

[image]

**Table visualization:**

[image]

**My attempt:**

I'm able to get distinct values per day as a measure using `dist = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Table1[Category]);DISTINCT(Table1[Date]))`

[image]

So what I'd like to end up with is the average of `dist` in the table above which is `1.67`. But how do you do that? I've tried different combinations with `AVERAGE`, `AVAREGEX`, `VALUES` and `CALCULATE`, but with no luck. And the more I try, the more I convince myself that DAX is useless (even though I know deep down it can't be). Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SUMMARIZE` to calculate the distinct count for each date, then you can use `AVERAGEX` to iterate over each date value:

```
dist:= 
IF ( 
    HASONEFILTER ( Table1[Date] ), 
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( Table1[Category] ), 
    AVERAGEX ( 
        SUMMARIZE ( 
            Table1, 
            Table1[Date],
            "Daily Average", DISTINCTCOUNT ( Table1[Category] )
        ),
        [Daily Average]
    )
)
```

EDIT: You don't really need the `IF` function - it seems to perform just as well using simply:

```
dist:= 
AVERAGEX ( 
    SUMMARIZE ( 
        Table1, 
        Table1[Date],
        "Daily Average", DISTINCTCOUNT ( Table1[Category] )
    ),
    [Daily Average]
)
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm! This is why DAX scares me a bit though. A seemingly easy task turns into a mess of nested functions really fast. Do you happen to know where to look If I would try to make it a bit less...complex? I thought `CALCULATE` (which some of my colleagues *always* use) would be the way to go, but I don't think so in this case.

Comment: It's not actually that complex! As always with nested DAX, read from the inside out. You need to perform the distinct count for each date in the evaluation context, so the first thing we do is use `SUMMARIZE` to create a summary table of date / distinct count (a virtual version of your first "table visualization" image. Then we use the `AVERAGEX` (iterator) function to calculate the average of the distinct counts for all dates in this virtual table. Finally, the `IF` statement is just there to perform the simple `DISTINCTCOUNT` when evaluated for only one date.

Comment: Thanks for the details! One last question if you don't mind. Do you write your expressions in Power BI, or in some other editor? DAXEditor perhaps? DAX Studio? I'm looking for an approach where you can more easily show each step in the calculations more easily. If that is even possible...

Comment: I usually just use Notepad++, and have good indent / newline discipline!!